# "Nothing to commit" depois de autenticação falhada

Tags: git

Estou com uma dúvida em relação ao git. Nomeadamente quando falhamos a autenticação, os comandos e acções que tomei foram:

1. Alteração em `ficheiro.c`
2. comando `git add .`
3. comando `git commit -am 'lol' && git push origin master`
4. pedido de autenticação
5. autenticação falhada
6. Repetir comando do passo 3, em que o output é:

> On branch master
> nothing to commit, working directory clean

No entanto o push não funcionou, as alterações (ponto 1) não estão no repostório

Comment: Tem que ser só `git push origin master` agora. O commit já foi feito, o que falhou foi o push.

Comment: @LINQ sim, creio que isso funciona. Pode responder em baixo

Comment: pronto[.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/233827/18246)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Os *commits* são locais, na sua máquina. Então, o que falhou foi apenas o `push`.

Ao invés de repetir o comando

```
git commit -am 'lol' && git push origin master
```

Apenas faça um `push`

```
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 2):

A mensagem:

> On branch master nothing to commit, working directory clean

diz que você está na branch master e não há nada para commitar no seu diretório de trabalho, pois em:

```
git commit -am 'lol' && git push origin master
```

O lado esquerdo do seu `&&` já havia sido executado, e portanto, quando você reexecuta todo o passo três recebe esta mensagem.

Sempre que houver um commit seu diretório de trabalho ficará limpo, isto pode ser verificado utilizando o comando `git status`.

Resta portanto reenviar o commit local para o servidor remoto utilizando o comando `git push origin master` que é o lado direito do seu passo três.